# Add image on key pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am trying to add image to canvas when I press keyboard button:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg"));

        Canvas.SetTop(img, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(img, 0);
        this.Content = img;
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<Canvas KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="166" Margin="118,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
```

But when I press a key nothing happens. If I put the same code in MainWindow method, it loads the picture. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Put breakpoint in the OnKeyDownHandler and determine if the event is fired. I guess it isn't because your Canvas is not focused.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your canvas a name and make the canvas focusable and then in your constructor focus on it.  Here is code snippet

```
<Canvas KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" Focusable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="166" Margin="118,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Name="myCanvas"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myCanvas.Focus(); //<-- Do this First

    }



    private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg"));

        Canvas.SetTop(img, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(img, 0);
        this.Content = img;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several points:

1. In your XAML you have to give your canvas a name, so you can relate to it from your code. Then you can use `MainCanvas.Children.Add(img);`
2. when you use the word `this`you refer to the instance of the class - your window, and not the canvas. `this.Content=` is same as writing `Content=`and will put the img on the window. this will happen directly immediately in the constructor
3. Last point is the focus: your canvas as defined in the xaml does not get the focus and your event is not fired. if you add a background to the canvas you can fire `MainCanvas_MouseDown`. Even with a background, you will not fire `KeyDown`.
4. Once you set the focus on the canvas and add `Focusable="True"` in the xaml, 'keyDown' will fire as well (as answered already by others)

xaml:

```
<Canvas Name="MainCanvas" Focusable="True" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="160" Margin="68,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" KeyDown="MainCanvas_KeyDown" MouseDown="MainCanvas_MouseDown_1" >
```

code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Image img = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Koala.jpg")) };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainCanvas.Focus();
        //this.Content = img; 
        //Content = img; //same as the above. you don't need to write "this".
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {// will work even if canvas has no background
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(img);
    }

    private void MainCanvas_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //event will not fire. Canvas does not get the focus
        //if you must have KeyDown trigger the event, you need MainCanvas.Focus() in the constructor, and Focusable="True" in the XAML.
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(img);
    }

    private void MainCanvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //This event will only fire if the canvas can get the focus: e.g. if it has some background.
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(img); //canvas control has the name MainCanvas inside the xaml
        //the below will work, but place the image on the window, because "this" means the class instance, not the method or event you are in.
        //this.Content = img;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think You should add weight + height and add the image to Canvas.Children

```
img.Width = value;
img.Height = value;
MyCanvas.Children.Add(img);
```